# MYSQL query only gets the last result?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a notification system using PHP/MYSQL.

in a way it works fine but I don't understand why it only gets the last result (Last ID).

this is my current code:

```
<?php
include "../config/connect.php";
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$query = "SELECT id, extendedd, alarm_signal FROM bookings";

$noti = '';
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $idc, $extendedd, $alarm_signal);

    /* fetch values */
   while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

       $extendeddd = $extendedd;

       //echo $extendeddd;

       if($extendedd =='yes'){


       $noti = '<div  id="mainNoti" style="position:fixed; right:30px; bottom:0; background-color:#F90; right:40px; width:400px; height:300px; border-radius:4px; border:dashed 2px #666; color:#000; text-align:center; padding-top:15px;"><form action="notification" method="post" id="addit"><input type="hidden" name="mesOff" id="mesOff"  value="1"/>
       <input class="btn2" type="submit" value="The job with id '.$idc.' has been extended!&nbsp;" />
       <br /><br /><br /><br />
       </form></div>';

       } else if ($extendedd == '0'){
         $noti = '';  
       }

   }
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
echo $noti;

?>
```

the code above works fine but it will only get the `$extendedd` of the last `$idc` and I don't understand why this is happening!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: You overwrite `$noti` on each iteration. Either put those values in a array or use concatenation.

Comment: You're overwriting $noti with every iteration. You should use `$noti +=`.

Comment: @ stakolee `+=` is not for string concatenation, `.=` is

Comment: @VolkerK, i did use .= as well and still getting the last $idc only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(....) {
  $noti = ...
}
echo $noti;
```

You're overwriting $noti in each iteration, therefore after the loop only the last value is accessible.
Either print the value of $noti within the while-loop.
Or append the new string to the current value of $noti via string concatenation: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: You should expand on your answer and offer a solution. Otherwise this is a comment.

Comment: sorry, took a few seconds to find the link

Comment: what is the difference between your given example and my code in my question?

Comment: It's just a condensed represeantion of what you're doing.

Comment: printing out the $noti in the while loop worked. Excellent and thank you.